# Merging Data Frames on Unique Values

Tags: python, pandas, merge, unique

I have 2 data frames.  One is a generic "template" with a column of dates that go every hour from now until 4 days from now.  The other DF has data in it, such as Latitude and Longitude, it also has a date column but the data is only every 3 hours.  I need to combine both data frames so that each lat/lon pair in df2 has an every hour from df1.

```
DF1                                DF2 
Date                 Shift         Latitude  Longitude   Date                 Temp
2021-10-18 01:00:00  a1            39.9      -99.3       2021-10-18 18:00:00  34
2021-10-18 02:00:00  a2            39.9      -99.3       2021-10-18 21:00:00  36
.....                              .............
2021-10-18 21:00:00  b2            39.9      -99.3       2021-10-19 00:00:00  32
```

Expected Final Data Frame

```
Latitude Longitude Date                 Shift           Temp
39.9     -99.3     2021-10-18 01:00:00  a1              NaN
39.9     -99.3     2021-10-18 02:00:00  a1              NaN
.....
39.9     -99.3     2021-10-18 17:00:00  b2              NaN
39.9     -99.3     2021-10-18 18:00:00  b2              34
39.9     -99.3     2021-10-18 19:00:00  b2              NaN
```

In DF2 there are 3,088 unique pairs of Lat/Lon and each of the unqiue pairs has to have a date column of 4 days, counting hour by hour.  My final DF should have 299,536 lines in it.

Comment: Where are the `b1`'s coming from in your expected output?

Comment: Sorry they were meant to be b2, they come from the DF1 original data frame

Comment: `df2.merge(df1, on='Date', how='outer')`?

Comment: That works to get every Date in DF1 populated.  However every pair of lat/lon in DF2 does not have every date in DF1.

Answer (score 0):

Use merge with the how and on options.
From the pandas [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['foo', 'bar'], 'b': [1, 2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['foo', 'baz'], 'c': [3, 4]})
df1.merge(df2, how='inner', on='a')
```

will give you:

```
      a  b  c
0   foo  1  3
```

while using:

```
df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='a')
```

will give you:

```
      a  b  c
0   foo  1  3.0
1   bar  2  NaN
```